# fadeTo blink hovering a border

Tags: jquery

i made a fast **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ckQfQ/6/)** of my **little** problem.

can anyone tell me why  my fadeTo are backing to the main opacity when i hover a border?

i think its a border problem, i can be roung, check the fiddle, hover a border and you will see the little blink that happens.

source:

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="title"></div>
<table width='100%' style='border-bottom: dotted 1px;'>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td class="align_center" width="50px">Two.</td>
        <td class="align_center" width="80px">Other</td>
        <td class="align_center" width="70px">Other 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="result" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

**css:**

```
#container{
   display: block;
   border: solid 1px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 130px;
   left: 3px;
   width: 500px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   opacity: 0.4;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);   
}
```

**js:**

```
$("#container").live("mouseover", function(){
     $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('slow', 1);
 });
 $("#container").live("mouseout", function(){
     $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('slow', 0.4);
 });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing it to `$(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);` seems to fix it for me. The second true was causing it to jump to the end of the animation (hence the blink).